# How does WolframAlpha calculate closed form approximations of irrational numbers?

Tags: wolfram-alpha-queries, approximation

How does WolframAlpha do this:

[image: approximation]

I'm aware of services such as [RIES](http://mrob.com/pub/ries/index.html), which is an inverse equation solver, and [ISC](https://isc.carma.newcastle.edu.au/advancedCalc), the Inverse Symbolic Calculator. But WA goes much further.

I've tried doing a literature search, but came up empty handed.

- What are the key-words one should use for such a literature search?
- What are the basic techniques being used here?
- Is it just a massively precomputed table lookup?

Comment: Try to search on "experimental mathematics" (in particular read the wiki article on this topic) and on the integer relation algorithms (in particular the PSLQ algorithm, which  was selected as one of the "Top Ten Algorithms of the Century"). You will see that it is *not a massively precomputed table lookup*. The algorithm is proved to discover a relation, but the empirical part is always to provide an information on what to relate. Here it is in a way a table look up.

Comment: Another interesting related topic is https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mathematical_coincidence . Have a look at Heegner numbers, a striking example is that $\exp(\pi\sqrt{163})$ is *almost integer*.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it concerns the working of Wolfram|Alpha, a topic which has been explicitly declared off-topic for this site.